# how to detect the checkbox checked event in formly angular7?

Tags: checkbox, angular7, angular-formly

Using formly and Json I created one form. Now I want display a text box when I checked the check box.

I tried with `ngDoCheck()` method, but I was unable to display the text. The `box.this` method hitted every field click event, although I need checked event only. Can any one help me out this.

```
"createConfig": [
{
    "columnName": "chkid",
    "columnSize": 50,
    "columnType": 5,
    "discreteValues": null,
    "displayName": "",
    "filterType": "e",
    "isEnabled": 1,
    "isMultiSelect": 0,
    "isRequired": 0,
    "isVisible": 1,
    "listDataProvider": null,
    "position": 2,
    "showSuggestion": 1,
    "sizeUnit": "px",
    "useDisplayValueOnly": 1
},
{
    "columnName":"nonusaddresa",
    "displayName": "Address1/Address2/City/State/Zip/PostalCode/Country",
    "position": 2,
    "columnType": 1,
    "isSortable": 0,
    "defaultSortOrder": null,
    "columnSize": 800,
    "sizeUnit": "px",
    "isVisible": 0,
    "isEnabled": 1,
    "isRequired": 0,
    "isMultiSelect": 0,
    "showSuggestion": 1,
    "useDisplayValueOnly": 1,
    "filterType": "e",
}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to `valueChanges` of form

```
    <formly-form #formlyForm
                 [model]="configModel"
                 [fields]="fields">
    </formly-form>
```

```
  @ViewChild(FormlyForm) public formlyForm: FormlyForm;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.formlyForm.form.valueChanges
    enter code here
  }
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe:

```
      .pipe(this.readUntilDestroyed())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Even in 2022, I had to find a workaround based on `id` generated by formly-form and the click event _ eg.

```
    this.app.objects[0].data.presentation[2][0].templateOptions.click = (field, event) => {
      if (event.target.firstChild.id === 'formly_9_multicheckbox_foo_0_5-input') { // the sixth checkbox
        // Notice : it was inverted because the checked is before setting value
        if (event.target.firstChild.checked) {
          // enabled another field 
          this.app.objects[0].data.presentation[3][0].templateOptions.disabled = false;
        } else {
          // disabled another field 
          this.app.objects[0].data.presentation[3][0].templateOptions.disabled = true;
        }
      }
    };
```

*This example is with **multicheckbox**.*

Answer (score -1):

***You need to have (change) event on input to see if the checkbox is checked or not***

```
 <input type="checkbox" (change)="checkMethod($event)">
```

**In your ts file**

```
  checkMethod(event)
{
if(event.target && event.target.checked)
{
//this means input is checked
}
}
```

Comment: this question is regarding angular formly, angular formly is a 3rd party library. The changes you suggested will work with angular but not with angular formly.